# Upgrading from 0.9.19 to 1.1.0 seems to break Page objects

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have a page object with this code:

```
var MyToolComp = require('./MyToolComponent').MyToolComponent;

var MyToolCommand = {

    get: function (cssLocator, timeout) {
        return new MyToolComp({client: this, locator: cssLocator, timeout: timeout});
    },

    assertMyToolCount: function (expectedMyToolesCount, timeoutMs) {
        console.log('Validate number of MyTool in the page to be [' + expectedMyToolesCount + ']');
        this.waitForElementsCount(this.section.john_container.selector, expectedMyToolesCount, timeoutMs);
        return this;
    },

};

module.exports = {
    commands: [MyToolCommand],

    sections: {
        john_container: {
            selector: '.john_container',
            elements: {
                john_MyTool: {
                    selector: '.john_MyTool'
                },
                header: {
                    selector: '.john_MyTool_header'
                }
            }
        },
        multi_widget: {
            selector: '.john_multi_widget'
        }
    }
};
```

After upgrading to 1.1.0, I can't run this code in my test:
    var myToolPage = browser.page.myTool();
    myToolPage.assertMyToolCount(1);

When debugging, I see myToolPage has "section" var, but no commands.
If I remove sections and only do
`module.exports = MyToolCommand;`

or

```
module.exports = {
    commands: [MyToolCommand]

}
```

Then I can run
`myToolPage.assertMyToolCount(1);`

But then it failes since
`this.section.john_container.selector`
Isn't defined.

What am I doing wrong? I can't find anything [here](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#page-objects) or [here](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Page-Object-API#enhanced-page-object-commands). Is there anything else I can read that'll help me? What else should I know when upgrading NW? (This is my first time seeing anything nightwatch-related so I kinda have to learn as I go).

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed this was replacing

```
module.exports = {
    commands: [MyToolCommand],

    sections: {
        john_container: {
            selector: '.john_container',
            elements: {
                john_MyTool: {
                    selector: '.john_MyTool'
                },
                header: {
                    selector: '.john_MyTool_header'
                }
            }
        },
        multi_widget: {
            selector: '.john_multi_widget'
        }
    }
};
```

With

```
exports.commands = MyToolCommand;
exports.sections = {
        john_container: {
            selector: '.john_container',
            elements: {
                john_MyTool: {
                    selector: '.john_MyTool'
                },
                header: {
                    selector: '.john_MyTool_header'
                }
            }
        },
        multi_widget: {
            selector: '.john_multi_widget'
        }
    };
```